# Помогите найти начальный индекс самой длинной последовательности

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, index

код выполняет следующую задачу : Написать программу, которая читая последовательность чисел из файла, выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию (в числах и символах) с которой она началась. Обязательное условие ( Данные должны считываться построчно)

```
import time,os,string,psutil,re
start_time = time.time()
res_list = []
res=''
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    s = file.read(symbol_len)  # Считываем первый символ
    if not s:  # Обработка исключения пустого файла
        print("\nФайл text.txt пустой.")
    else:
        for line in file.readlines():
            x = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            if x:
                res_list.extend(x)

    res_list.append(res)
    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    print(f'Самая длинная восходящая последовательность чисел   - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\n')
    print('как найти начальный индекс?')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Где ваша собственная попытка решить задачу? На этом сайте помогают, а не делают задания вместо вас. Поэтому -  ждем вашего варианта решения, конкретных вопросов -  что у вас не получается. Вот на них тут с удовольствием отвечают.

Comment: решил,поправил,посмотрите в профиле